# Importing local images in React js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, file, import

I searched up on how to do relative paths and absolute paths etc. but I just cannot seem to import the local images correctly. My ultimate goal is to create a react slide show with these images. What is wrong with this right now? Why is it trying to find the images in "components" when I told them to look in "media"?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in import.
The image is called `wecome_back_image1.jpg`,  but you are importing it as `welcome_back_image1.jpg`. 
You are missing the character `l`. 
Please, try to avoid of asking questions with screenshots. Add the code instead. 
 It will help other developers to understand and help you easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in the file. In the slideshow.js file, the name is "welcome" but the actual file says "wecome". You are missing an "l"